# C - Error in Comparing Variable of Struct and String

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a function that compares two strings. However, i am getting "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" in function strcmp even if i use char pointers instead of char array. My code is in following.

```
typedef enum { false, true } boolean;

struct threeGram *threeGram_array;

struct threeGram
{
    const char *value;
    int occurence;
};

boolean containsValue(struct threeGram array[], const char *string){

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof (array) / sizeof (struct threeGram); i++){
        if(strcmp(array[i].value, string) = 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `) = 0` is an assignment, not a comparison

Comment: And unrelated, but `sizeof (array) / sizeof (struct threeGram)` does not give you the size of the array, since `array` decayed to a pointer

Comment: Thank you UnholySheep. That was the problem.

Comment: Do you suggest any thing for to get max limit of loop ? I am trying to get the length of my array passed into function...

Comment: Get a better compiler. You should get a warning/error for this code. The result of strcmp is not even a lvalue. Out of curiousity, which trash compiler let this code through?

Comment: @Lundin OP is already getting a compiler **error**. In what sense is a warning better?

Comment: @Lundin I am using Visual Studio Code. Which one should i use ? Can you suggest one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking for equality in `C` you should use double equals `==` otherwise this is interpreted as assignment. Thus on this line:

```
if(strcmp(array[i].value, string) = 0){
```

You try to assign a result to function return value which is non-modifiable lvalue.